# Difference in Android test transaction with real one

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, google-play, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I'm working on in-app purchases in my game. Currently I'm verifying the transaction whether it's test or real transaction with the signature getting from google. This is not checking my test transaction. I couldn't find the difference between real one and test one. Is there any other way to get it done?

Comment: Show us your code

Answer (score 0):

[Help on testing billing is here](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing). That page describes the different ways of testing. Many of the test purchases are intentionally the same as real purchases to make your tests properly realistic.

You shouldn't rely on the app itself to distinguish test and real purchases. But you could look at the product id for the simple case.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to find whether the subscription is purchased by a genuine customer or a license test account, you can get that data from the Google Purchases.subscriptions API for more details [refer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55588840/9522887) my answer.